# How to compute the average of dictionary's value made up of lists,?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, average

I have to compute the average of lists of values of a dictionary,:

```
d={('a'):['-','-',3.2],
   ('b'):[4.8,6.7],
   ('c'):['-'],
   ('d'):[6.7,'-',9.8,'-']}
```

I would like to have:

```
d={('a'):[3.2],
    ('b'):[5.75],
    ('c'):['-'],
    ('d'):[8.25]}
```

this is the code I used :

```
avgd={}

for key, v in d.iteritems():
    try:
        avgd[key]=sum(v)/(len(v))
    except TypeError:
        avgd[key]='-'
```

But I get only the average of whose list are only composed by numbers.
How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Are the non number items *always* a dash?

Comment: On a sidenote, it looks like you are trying to implement functionality that is covered by masked arrays from numpy. You might wish to look into that if your real-life problems are somewhat more complex.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, yes they are always dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  I use a list comprehension to only grab the relevant items of `v`.

```
>>> for key,v in d.iteritems():
    try:
        nums = [i for i in v if i != '-']
        avgd[key] = sum(nums) / len(nums)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        avgd[key] = '-'


>>> avgd
{'a': 3.2, 'c': '-', 'b': 5.75, 'd': 8.25}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={('a'):['-','-',3.2],
   ('b'):[4.8,6.7],
   ('c'):['-'],
   ('d'):[6.7,'-',9.8,'-']}

avgd = {}

for key, values in d.iteritems():
    numeric = [float(i) for i in values if isinstance(i,(int,float))]
    avgd[key] = [sum(numeric)/len(numeric)] if numeric else values

# avgd == {'a': [3.2], 'c': ['-'], 'b': [5.75], 'd': [8.25]}
```

Comment: if d has item like ('e'):  ['-', '-'] , then after process the avgd['e'] will not be ['-'], so I think you probably should change values to ['-'] . :-)

Comment: @Alice I'm glad! Be sure to mark the answer that solves your problem with a green check.

Answer (score 0):

By skipping instead of blowing up.

```
{k:('-' if all(e == '-' for e in v) else
  (sum(e for e in v if e != '-') / (sum(1 for e in v if e != '-')) or 1))
  for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

Optimization is left as an exercise for the reader.